# Solving small part file issue in HDFS using coalesce

Tags: apache-spark

Small part file issue is a problem for HDFS storage as it increases the Metadata load for Name node. To reduce this problem can we use coalesce to reduce the partitions and then save the dataframe in HDFS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My question is related to Apache spark..I m looking for a solution to resolve small files issue in HDFS!!